# kogito does not show scheduled jobs

Tags: kogito

The symptom of the problem is that using kogito (version 1.41), creating a new job via post to v2/jobs. The database entry in the job_details table appears. Job generally works, executes. However, on the kogito Management Console/Jobs Management console nothing appears. The grapgql return returns an empty return: { "data":{ "Jobs":[]}}.
Has anyone perhaps encountered such a problem?
Orders of ordinary processes set aside in the database in the **processes** table appear without a problem while jobs not;

Comment: Been running into something similar. Have you had any luck?